# $routeProvider has stopped working

Tags: angularjs

I can't get $routeProvider to work correctly anymore. I got a skinned down version of the situation as a Plunker see:
http://plnkr.co/edit/7G9WnT5i4qA01icAUAY5?p=preview

This is app.routes.js

```
angular.module('app.routes', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })

        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

It should load the template home.html but nothing happens.
I am using angular-route after angular and using ng-view in the index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@2.0.0-alpha.31" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="app.routes.js"></script>
    <script src="homeCtrl.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="homeController">
    this is the index.html page
    <div ng-view> </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I have been going cross-eyed staring at this for a hour or more and can't see where the problem is.

Comment: In your script.js file do this angular.module('testApp', ['app.routes']);

Comment: You have multiple issues with this example.  1.  the version of Angular.js and the version of angular-route.js must match **exactly**.  2.  This example appears to try to use an alpha version of angular2, which *is not* the same as angular.js 1.x, and angular-route.js does not work with it.

Comment: Oh I didn't noticed it. Yes what @Claies said was right. You are loading alpha version of angular2. Change angular version to 1.x

Comment: @BKM yes you were right, not injecting app.routes was stuffing it up. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check working demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2QNg9e3ozqwcl8hkjrGi?p=preview).

Modifications done:

1. Change angular version to 1.3.8
2. Add module dependency:

   `var MyApp = angular.module('testApp', ['app.routes']);`
3. Remove `homeController` everywhere since it is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the plunk. The killer mistake was not injecting app.routes - total brain fade!